# How to convert number (price) in to multiples of 0.05 using AutoHotKey script?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I was automating a trading software using AHK script. During price submission the app does not accept in between values, say between 1.50 and 1.55. It only accepts multiples of 0.05 because its tick-size is 0.05 hence i have to do the price conversion using AHK script.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
Round(N / 0.05) * 0.05
```

### Example

```
Round(1.53 / 0.05) * 0.05 ; Returns 1.55
```

### Explanation

I'm going to explain with 0.01 because it's easier to visualize, but it applies to any number. The number to round is 1.234. Anything after 3 will need to be discarded in the rounding process.

If we divide the number 1.234 by 100, we get 123.4. Note how the period is after 3. So we can just use `Round` now.

After rounding, the number is 123. Now we just need to scale it back down by multiplying by 0.01, which results in 1.23.

### Formatting

As [0x464e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813732/0x464e) pointed out in the comments, due how floating-point numbers work, the result may be imprecise. So if you're going to convert them to strings, do so using `Format("{:.2f}", number)`.

The `2` comes from the minimum number of decimal places needed to accurately represent any number multiple of 0.05. By the way, this can be calculated by using:

```
Ceil(Log(1 / 0.05)) ; Returns 2
```

Comment: Nice one, throw it inside a `Format("{:.2f}", input)` as well, since returning a value with 2 decimal points of precision seemed to be important.

Comment: Brief and beautiful!, could you please explain the math of how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following AHK function Roundoff converts and returns the price in its nearest tick-size multiple.

```
Roundoff(price) ;round off to nearest 5 paisa value
{
    price := Round(price, 2) ;ronded to 2 decimal places
    priceNoDecimal := Floor(price)
    decimalPart :=  price - priceNoDecimal
    decimalPart := Floor( Round(decimalPart * 100, 2) )
    numerator := Floor(decimalPart / 5)
    remainder := Mod(decimalPart, 5)
    if ( remainder > 2)
        retval := (numerator * 5) + 5
    if ( remainder < 3)
        retval := (numerator * 5)
    retval := Round(priceNoDecimal + (retval / 100), 2)
    return retval
}
```